# [Fourier Analysis with database]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy, fft

I have a file of water surface elevation and I would like to know the caracteristic period and amplitude. 
So I wanted to do a Fourier analysis with python but I do not arrived.

My file is like this :

- Col 0 : Time,
- Col 2 : Elevation

I did the following code :

```
df=pd.read_csv(file,sep=';',header=None)
df.columns=['Time','Nothing','HS','Other1','Other2']
N=len(df)
T=df.loc[0,'Time']-df.loc[len(df)-1,'Time'] #Intervalle de temps
freq=np.linspace(0.0, 1, N) #Vecteur fréquence 
 
HSf=scipy.fft(df['HS']) #Transformée de Fourier
plt.plot(freq,abs(HSf))
```

The problem is that by doing this, I have the first element of HSf that corresponds to the peak. And obsiouvsly, it will correspond to the first element of my vector freq (0).

I know that the period must be around 5-8 s but I want to find it with this kind of analysis.

Could you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please clarify your question. You create the plot of an amplitude spectrum. This seems to be working, so what is the problem?

Comment: So what your saying is that the zero frequency component (i.e. baseline) is the strongest but you're looking for the strongest oscillatory component with freq>0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly but if it's that your 0th frequency component is the strongest but you're not interested in that, I see two options:

(1) Instead of looking at the full spectrum, ignore th first element:

```
plt.plot(freq[1:],abs(HSf)[1:])
```

(2) Subtract the baseline before doing the FFT:

```
HSf=scipy.fft(df['HS']-np.mean(df['HS']))
```

---

Edit:
I'm also nut sure if your frequency axis makes any sense in your application. You might want to have a look at [numpy.fft.fftfreq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html#numpy.fft.fftfreq).

Comment: Finally it is good, I have found how to make a good frequency axis :
np.fft.fftfreq(N,dt) with dt the sample time and N the length of my signal !

Comment: Well, then some appreciation by upvoting or accepting would be very kind.